# SQL Server: select where multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_feedback 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And I want to just select where the column 'status' have the string/varchar "done" and the column 'type' is a "bug".

Comment: This would be covered in the most basic SQL tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward

```
SELECT
*
FROM tbl_feedback
WHERE
    [status] = 'done'
    AND [type] = 'bug'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess - for more details please provide table schema and some demo data.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_feedback WHERE [status] = 'done' AND [type] = 'bug' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: No problem, a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you need add conditions with where clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_feedback 
WHERE status = 'done' and type= 'bug' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

here is [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e3c5/1) to play with

You can also use columns names to filter out only required column in select as

```
SELECT status, type 
FROM tbl_feedback 
WHERE status = 'done' and type= 'bug' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: As i already said to @dhh It's `SQL Server` and not `MySQL`, wrapping varchar with " instead of ' won't work there.